# Salesforce Wsdl not valid any more

Tags: soap-api, webservices, wsdl, service, enterprise-wsdl

I tried today to generate a proxy with the `entreprise.wsdl` file (also tried with `partner.wsdl`) and noticed that the file was 'not valid'.

When generating the proxy, everything seems to be okay, but at runtime (I'm writing a client in C#, but this probably doesn't play any role) an exception is raised on this line:

```
SForceService service = new SForceService();
```

The error is:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in System.Xml.dll Additional information: Temporäre Klasse
>   kann nicht generiert werden (result=1).
>
> error CS0030: Eine Konvertierung vom Typ
>   'Entreprise.ListViewRecordColumn[]' in
>   'Entreprise.ListViewRecordColumn' ist nicht möglich.
>
> error CS0030: Eine Konvertierung vom Typ
>   'Entreprise.ListViewRecordColumn[]' in
>   'Entreprise.ListViewRecordColumn' ist nicht möglich.
>
> error CS0029: Eine implizite Konvertierung vom Typ
>   'Entreprise.ListViewRecordColumn' in
>   'Entreprise.ListViewRecordColumn[]' ist nicht möglich.
>
> error CS0029: Eine implizite Konvertierung vom Typ
>   'Entreprise.ListViewRecordColumn' in
>   'Entreprise.ListViewRecordColumn[]' ist nicht möglich.

The translation in english should be something like this:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in System.Xml.dll. Additional information: A temporary class
>   cannot be generated (result=1)
>
> error CS0030: An implicit conversion from type
>   "Entreprise.ListViewRecordColumn[]' to
>   'Entreprise.ListViewRecordColumn' is not possible.
>
> error CS0030 : An implicit conversion from type
>   'Entreprise.ListViewRecordColumn[]' to
>   'Entreprise.ListViewRecordColumn' is not possible.
>
> error CS0029: An implicit conversion from type
>   'Entreprise.ListViewRecordColumn' to
>   'Entreprise.ListViewRecordColumn[]' is not possible.
>
> error CS0029: An implicit conversion from type
>   'Entreprise.ListViewRecordColumn' to
>   'Entreprise.ListViewRecordColumn[]' is not possible.

using an old wsdl file (downloaded from Salesforce last year) fixed the problem, but this is not a solution for me since I created a lot of new objects that are not in this old wsdl file...

Does anybody have the same problem? How to fix this?

Comment: I don't suppose you could provide the error messages in English somehow?

Comment: See my edited post for the english translation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like it could be a bug in .NET's XML serializer:

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000205824&language=en_US

Comment: I followed the instructions of the link you provided which basically says that one should replace all occurences of `[][]` with `[]` and....... it works! Excellent! thank you...

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it is a bug. It's due to the fact that the ListViewRecord object only has a single elements, "columns", which is a collection of ListViewRecordColumn objects. .NET reads the WSDL, but skips over making the ListViewRecord class entirely.

That's why you're seeing [][]... fixing it to [] makes it *compile*, but it's not "right". It should be ListViewRecord[].

So, to fix this, first open the Reference.cs which contains the C# that was auto-generated from then WSDL (assuming you're using Connected Services, instead of Web References, which was .NET-2-era). Around line 11883 (yikes!), I introduced the ListViewRecord class by hand. It looks like this

```
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.7.2102.0")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com")]
    public partial class ListViewRecord : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private ListViewRecordColumn[] columnsField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(IsNullable = true, Order = 1)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("records", typeof(ListViewRecordColumn), IsNullable=false)]
        public ListViewRecordColumn[] columns
        {
            get
            {
                return this.columnsField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.columnsField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("columns");
            }
        }

        public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
            if ((propertyChanged != null))
            {
                propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

With that, I then went through and found all (3?) of the references to ListViewRecordColumn[][], and changed them to ListViewRecord[]. Essentially, preserving "the array of things that holds an array of ListViewRecordColumns" the idea by following the WSDL and putting that latter array behind a .columns property.

It is a shame that Microsoft isn't addressing this bug, because they never, ever will. It's also a shame that Salesforce had the gumption to introduce ListViewRecord when it only served as a thin/useless container for ListViewRecordColumns. Bug vs poor design? I dunno, but given Salesforce's track record with its partner WSDL (which isn't even valid), I can't lay blame solely at Microsoft's door.